# Render function in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a small component in VueJS by rendering the function, following is my `<table>` component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th v-for="item in headers">
                        {{ item.title }}
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(item, index) in contents">
                    <!--<th scope="row">-->
                        <!--{{ index+1 }}-->
                    <!--</th>-->
                    <td v-for="{ key } in headers">
                        {{ item[key] }}
                    </td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

For which I've made a following render function:

```
render (createElement) {
    return createElement('table', {class: 'table'}, [
        createElement('thead', {}, [
            createElement('tr',
                this.headers.map(a => createElement('th', a.title)))
        ], createElement('tbody',
            this.contents.map(b => createElement('tr',
                this.headers.map(c => createElement('td', c[key]))))))
    ])
}
```

I'm getting an error of

> Error in render: "ReferenceError: key is not defined"

FYI my data set looks something like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        headers: [
            { title: '#', key: 'index' },
            { title: 'First Name', key: 'first_name'},
            { title: 'Last Name', key: 'last_name'},
            { title: 'Username', key: 'username' }
        ],
        contents: [
            { index: 1, first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Stone', username: '@john' },
            { index: 2, first_name: 'Lisa', last_name: 'Nilson', username: '@lisa' },
            { index: 3, first_name: 'Larry', last_name: 'the Bird', username: '@twitter' }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how can we take out the keys from `map` of `headers` dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an issue with the way you have structured your `createElement` calls (the first array is incorrect). If you layout your code correctly you'll be able to see it.

- I'd rename `createElement` to `h` to make it easier to read (`h` is the convention).
- `c[key]` should be `b[c.key]`.
- Using `a`, `b` and `c` as variable names is discouraged, use descriptive names.
- Using `staticClass` instead of `class` here is a minor optimization.

Untested:

```js
render(h) {
  return h('table', { staticClass: 'table' }, [
    h('thead', [
      h('tr', this.headers.map(header =>
        h('th', header.title)
      ))
    ]),
    h('tbody', this.contents.map(item =>
      h('tr', this.headers.map(header =>
        h('td', item[header.key])
      ))
    ))
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 2):

wrong brackets

```
    return createElement('table', { class: 'table' }, [
      createElement('thead', {}, [
        createElement('tr',
          this.headers.map(a => createElement('th', a.title)))
      ]), <--here
      createElement('tbody', 
        this.contents.map(b => createElement('tr',
            this.headers.map(c => createElement('td', b[c['key']]))
          )
        )
      )
    ])
```

Comment: Error is gone, but I am unable to render the table!

Comment: I mean the table headers are rendered but the contents are not being rendered, can you look what mistake I'm doing during `this.contents.map(b => createElement('tr'......`

Comment: I've never seen vuejs, but are you getting in your table the values "index", "first_name", and so..? If you do, why don't you try to do: `b[c["key"]]` in this way you will get the attribute of what c["key"] gives you. @NitishKumar

Comment: Yes I got that. well thanks for the help @BrankVictoria

Comment: Does it work for you to put `b[c["key"]]` ? Let me help you on this so I can understand this tool as well :D